# TypeScript: Catch variable signature of a function passed as argument in higher order function

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I would like for a higher order function to be able to catch the signature parameters of the passed function which can have different signature.

I don't know if it's feasible but this was my approach to it :

```js
type FuncA = (a: string, b: number) => void
type FuncB = (a: string) => void

type Func = FuncA | FuncB

const a: FuncA = (a: string, b: number) => {
  console.log('FuncA')
}

const b: FuncB = (a: string) => {
  console.log('FuncB')
}

// My higher order function
const c = (func: Func) => {
  // do something here...
  return (...args: Parameters<typeof func>) => {
    func(...args) // Expected 2 arguments, but got 0 or more. ts(2556). An argument for 'a' was not provided.
  }
}
```

My higher order function `c` couldn't pass the parameters of `func`
It seems like TypeScript cannot discriminate the different possible signature of type `Func`.

Does anyone know a pattern to write this kind of code?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tough one because for a function to `extend` another function doesn't mean quite what you think.

We want the function created by `c` to require that arguments correspond to the function that it was given.  So we use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) to describe the function.

```
const c = <F extends Func>(func: F) => {
  return (...args: Parameters<F>) => {
    func(...args); // still has error
  }
}
```

At this point we still have that error, but when we call `c`, we get a function which has the right arguments based on whether we gave it `a` or `b`.

```
const cA = c(a); // type: (a: string, b: number) => void
cA("", 0);

const cB = c(b); // type: (a: string) => void
cB("");
```

As for the error, it has to do with what it means for a function to extend another function.  Try changing `F extends Func` to `F extends FuncA` and `F extends FuncB` to see what happens.  With `F extends FuncB` we get an error on `c(a)`, but with `F extends FuncA` we don't get an error on `c(b)`.  Huh?

If you think about it in terms of a callback it makes sense.  It's ok to pass a function that requires less arguments than expected, but not ok to pass one that requires more.  But we are the ones implementing the callback so this creates a problem for us.  If we extend `type Func` with a function that has no arguments, the empty array from `Parameters<F>` isn't sufficient to call either type.

We have to make our generic depend on the arguments instead.

```
type AP = Parameters<FuncA> // type: [a: string, b: number]
type BP = Parameters<FuncB> // type: [a: string]

type Args = AP | BP;

const c = <A extends Args>(func: (...args: A) => void) => {
  return (...args: A) => {
    func(...args) // no error
  }
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMYEEoF4oAoCGAuKAZ2ACcBLBAcwBooAjAhOAWzohIEoMA%20KANwD2ZACYBYAFChIsREgBCGbPiKkKlLul6CREiVOjxkiw6igAfGcjm7xSAQmJRlJtJlwFi5KrQZQmrdg1eAG8JKCg7BwEAGwgAOmiBSiwAchcUjgkAXxtIx18TBTdlTzUgqFDxcLyY%20MTktNk5DOybfSgUAAVFTpwSHGYIYHZCAB4XXgB6Sah9AgBtEtVvekYWNhIAXT1waDluzF7%20weGSMcKpmbmoRY9lym3xHekUEkpCRS7zKH2AbhtplAALIgKAACzIlDB7CgAhIwhhADNZMAyPYJHlgBFFKM0BAAB7DBDCD6vd7cLDI5AELBxOl9d4EFDlbTCcqVcKA4QCIgCE4Qqjg9jxOlhKAkIZwEgIbB0uIMwhM9li8JUpC0%20lvQhcQEAUXxkCQw2EUAATE43iwIAhgIQfHAsZQBFiAAywkhQZhw%20KzQhYU0AVgDADYOHEOjKGVabVBEXCoCkcCkoAB3HAfBDOqBgEgCPgiCDCOJinLiUsY%20yOUyYdU4Di-KCA67uFReGirPzrQI8fhCMS2FBYABEQ9oLvruUrWPkinVdHrjauuxpSzbLL7GLkw6H9aAA)

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with the decorated function being any function, you could do:

```
const c = <T extends (...a: any) => any>(func: T) => {
  // do something here...
  return (...args: Parameters<typeof func>): ReturnType<T> => {
    return func(...args);
  }
}
```

Calling it would look like

```
c<typeof a>(a)('a', 2)
```